# Assigning file to another file in Pascal

Tags: file, pascal

Consider I have a file with information about employees(the employees repeat on that file). I have to create a new file of the same type(with the same information), but the only change I have to make is I need to accumulate on a variable an amount that is common in every employee(salary). **As the employees repeat on the first file**, I have to accumulate the salary on a variable and then upload it to the new file, of course checking if the employee has changed or not on the first file.

*After that I need to 'replace' the first file with the new one(with all the updated info). I don't know how to do this. Here's my code:*

```
     Assign(firstFile, 'employeesFile');
     createFirstFile(firstFile);  //this creates the 'old' file
     Assign(NEWfile, 'NEWEmployeesFile');
     updateInformation(firstFile, NEWfile); //this creates the new file, with updated information
```

What should I do next? I applied this code, but it throws an error message:

> Assign(firstFile, NEWfile);

*ERROR: Incompatible type por arg no. 2: got FILE, expected CHAR*

Comment: Just write to the new file and once you're finished, rename the old file to a similar name, e.g. `employeesFile.old` and then rename `NEWEmployeesFile` to `employeesFile`. The *.old file is a backup, just in case something went wrong. Then you can manually delete the wrong file and re-rename the .old file to its original name. You can't simply use Assign. That only associates a name with a FILE variable and creates a file record with info about the file.

Comment: You just need to read the plethora of documentation and examples that exist online for Pascal's file I/O functions. Try a Google search on "pascal process text files" or "copy text file in pascal," for example. From what you've written so far, it looks like you're just guessing at what the functions, like `Assign`, actually do.

Comment: sounds like you need a rename or renamefile function.

Comment: FWIW, error messages usually make a lot of sense. So just look at what the error message says, and perhaps search the error message in the documentation or online, e.g. https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userse63.html#x177-184000C.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the second parameter must be a String (The file name associated to the variable of type **File**).

Suppose you have already the two files, if you need to make a replace you should:
1- Erase the original file.
2- Rename the second file to  the same filename as the previous (deleted) file.

1-

```
Erase(FirstFile);
```

erases assigned file on variable "FirstFile". Be careful: File variable must be assigned, but not opened. See https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/erase.html.

2-

```
Rename(NEWFile,'employeesFile');
```

renames assigned file to the new name specified in the 2nd parameter. You can't rename if destination name already exists. Again: File variable must be assigned, but not opened.  See https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/rename.html for more information.